# y and x axis subplots matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

A quite basic question about ticks' labels for x and y-axis. According to this code

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,12, figsize=(50, 24), constrained_layout=True, sharex=True , sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .5, wspace=.5)
custom_xlim = (-1, 1)
custom_ylim = (-0.2,0.2)

for i in range(72):

   x_data = ctheta[i]
   y_data = phi[i]
   y_err = err_phi[i]

   ax = fig.add_subplot(6, 12, i+1)
   ax.plot(x_data_new, bspl(x_data_new))
   ax.axis('off')
   ax.errorbar(x_data,y_data, yerr=y_err, fmt="o")
   ax.set_xlim(custom_xlim)
   ax.set_ylim(custom_ylim)
```

I get the following output:

[image: parameter exstimation]

With y labels for plots on the first column and x labels for theone along the last line, although I call them off.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you doing `ax = fig.add_subplot(6, 12, i+1)`  - you already have all the subplots you need from `fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,12...`

Comment: you are totally right, I've fixed it with `for i,ax in zip(range(72),axes.flatten()):`

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen wrote in their comment, your issue is caused by you adding axes to your figure *twice*, once via `fig, axes = plt.subplots()` and then once again within your loop via `fig.add_subplot()`. As a result, the first set of axes is still visible even after you applied `.axis('off')` to the second set.

Instead of the latter, you could change your loop to:

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(12):
        ax = axes[i,j] # these are the axes created via plt.subplots(6,12,...)
        ax.axis('off')
        # … your other code here
```

Comment: thank you, I have solved it with for i,ax in zip(range(72),axes.flatten()):